# How do I repair broken bathtub faucet handles?

Tags: faucet, bathtub

How can I repair the faucet handles on my bathtub? It snapped off then when I was trying to use it; it shot off the wall and water constantly pours out where the handles go.

Comment: this really needs some photos

Answer (score 1):

Its likely the whole cartridge will need replacement. With it you will get a new handle stem.

This might be a sign to replace the whole unit.  If you have a three handle setup, a cover plate will let you upgrade to any single handle style.  If you go this route, be sure to get a tub filler spout WITH diverter (the single handle tub/shower valves usually don't have diverters.

[image]